# Android and Google Maps API in Israel

Tags: android, google-maps

how come I don't see detailed Israel map when I integrate with the MapView in my MapActivity?
I can see just about any other country except Israel.

thanks, 
Ori

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=492038

Comment: it is thought to be a security threat.  similarly, the rooftop of many federal buildings in Washington DC were obfuscated for quite awhile.

Comment: Another related post:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/3e2251435fe8dbde/1bd86decd7bf0c94?lnk=gst&q=israel#1bd86decd7bf0c94

Comment: And... http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=664

Answer (score 7):

Because the Israeli Government wanted Google Maps to do so:

http://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-maps-limiting-resolution-of-israel-satellite-images/2703/